# Line distance between points (p,q) and (q,p)

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to find the distance between the points `(p,q)` and `(q,p)`. As far as I can tell, my steps are correct, but I'm getting the answer 
$\sqrt{2q^2 + 2p^2}$ but the textbook gives the answer $\sqrt{2(p-q)^2}$. Can anyone check my steps please, and tell me what, if anything I'm doing wrong:

> \begin{split}
> x_2 &= q\\
> x_1 &= p\\
> y_2 &= p\\
> y_1 &= q\\
> \\
> x_2 - x_1 &= q - p\\
> y_2 - y_1 &= p - q\\
> \\
> \text{ distance }&= \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2} + \sqrt{(y_2 - y_1)^2}\\
> \\
> \text{ (plugging} &\text{ in values)}\\
> \\
> \text{ distance } &=\sqrt{(q-p)^2} + \sqrt{(p-q)^2}\\
> \\
> \text{($-p$ and $-q$ squared turn to $p^2$ } &\text{ and $q^2$, removing negative signs:)}\\
> \\
> &=\sqrt{q^2} + \sqrt{p^2} + \sqrt{p^2} + \sqrt{q^2}\\
> \\
> &=\sqrt{2q^2} + \sqrt{2p^2}
> \end{split}

The textbook answer however is $\sqrt{2(p-q)^2}$. Re-reading it, it did say to assume $p > q > 0$. Would that have changed the values / results?

Thanks and sorry about the formatting - first time poster.

Comment: You can't manipulate square roots that way.  $\sqrt {A+B}\neq \sqrt A +\sqrt B$ unless at least  one of $A,B$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, that was just my attempt at having the square root look like it dragged across both numbers. :P

Comment: No...you systematically wrote things like $\sqrt {(p-q)^2}+\sqrt {(q-p)^2}$ where you should have written $\sqrt {(p-q)^2+(q-p)^2}$.  Similarly, you appear to believe that $(p-q)^2 =p^2+q^2$ which is false.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root doesn't distribute. That is to say,

$$\sqrt{a + b} \neq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$$

in general. (There are specific examples and cases where it does equal and *looks* like it distributes, but it doesn't always happen. For example, above, consider $a=4,b=9$.)

Therein lies one of your problems.

---

Also, we note, once you get to the step where

$$d = \sqrt{(q-p)^2 + √(p-q)^2}$$

notice that $(p-q)^2 = (q-p)^2$. If you have trouble convincing yourself of this, remember you can factor out a $-1$ from one of them and thus:

$$(q-p)=-1(p-q)$$

implying

$$(q-p)^2 = (q-p)(q-p) = (-1)(p-q)(-1)(p-q) = (-1)^2(p-q)^2 = (p-q)^2$$

This is probably the most confusing step of the textbook's solution. From there it should be clear how to proceed.

Comment: I know the square root doesn't distribute - I couldn't figure out how to format it so to be clear, I added it to both numbers. But, thanks a bunch for explaining that `(q-p)^2 = (p-q)^2` . Do you happen to know if there are any khan academy videos or such explaining this more so I can look more into this? Thanks.

Comment: I think `(q-p)^2` evaluates to `q^2 + p^2` and `(p-q)^2` evaluates to the same thing, i.e `p^2 + q^2`, and that's why they are both equal and can be factored out. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. Just like the square root, exponentiation doesn't distribute. Remember:

$$(q-p)^2 = (q-p)(q-p)$$

Try FOILing that out, and see what you get.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why `(q-p)^2 = (p-q)^2`. My attempt was that they evaluate to the same thing if you open the brackets. Is there another indicator to recognize situations like this? Also, the answer would be valid either as `2(p-q)^2` or `2(q-p)^2` since they are equal - right?

Comment: An alternative way to see that $(q-p)^2 = (p-q)^2$, aside from what I showed, would be to FOIL out each expression, since

$$(q-p)^2 = (q-p)(q-p) \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; (p-q)^2 = (p-q)(p-q)$$

I wouldn't know about any sort of "indicator" for situations like this, you just learn to recognize them with experience. And yes, you could use $2(p-q)^2$ or $2(q-p)^2$ since they're equal; which of the two you choose is purely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The distance is

$$
d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}
$$

If you replace your points

$$
d = \sqrt{(p - q)^2 + (q - p)^2} = \sqrt{(p - q)^2 + (p - q)^2} = \sqrt{2(p - q)^2} = \sqrt{2} |p - q|
$$

Comment: Thank you for the steps, this helped me see the solution, but the other answer's explanation helped me understand why, so i had to accept that.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I’m glad you found the solution you’re looking for